# Log method name and parameters with NLog

Tags: .net, nlog

How to log calling method with its incoming parameters using NLog? If it's not possible: can I pass some parameters to logger, so that they will appear in the final log message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog allows you to capture [additional context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context) with the LogEvent:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, null, "Pass my custom value");
theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
theEvent.Properties["MyDateTimeValue"] = new DateTime(2015, 08, 30, 11, 26, 50);
theEvent.Properties["MyDateTimeValueWithCulture"] = new DateTime(2015, 08, 30, 11, 26, 50);
theEvent.Properties["MyDateTimeValueWithCultureAndFormat"] = new DateTime(2015, 08, 30, 11, 26, 50);
logger.Log(theEvent);
```

Can then be extracted using `${all-event-properties}`

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/All-Event-Properties-Layout-Renderer

You can automatically capture method-name by creating your own log-method with `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] methodName` as parameter. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute

And if using `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` to acquire the logger for the class, then you can use `${logger}` to render the class-name.

NLog v5 introduces a new [fluent-Logger-API](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Logger-API), that captures source-file + line-number + class-name with minimal overhead for use with [${callsite:captureStackTrace=false}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer):

```cs
_logger.ForInfoEvent()
       .Message("This is a fluent message {0}", "test")
       .Property("PropertyName", "PropertyValue")
       .Log();
```

Comment: nlog have a build-in renderer ${callsite} for namespace + classname + method name. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer

Comment: @Vladislav Yes but it has a performance penalty. Unless calling LogEventInfo.SetCallerInfo https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/M_NLog_LogEventInfo_SetCallerInfo.htm (And using NLog 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

One of ways to solve this - create custom wrapper under NLog logger class, that will take extra params like className and methodName. After that construct message yourself. You can use this also:

- [How to get information about calling method and class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849367/how-to-determine-calling-method-and-class-name)
- [MSDN Caller Information - get infomcation about caller for visual studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)