# How to determine calling method and class name?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm currently developing a application logging library using the built in TraceListener. This library will be used in many projects and should offer a simple interface where I only have to care about WHAT is going to be written in into the log file, but not HOW.

By using the reflection namespace, I can figure out which application currently called a log function (retrieving execution assembly name), but I want also the name of the function and class that called the logging function.

Let's say I have:

```
public static void LogInfo(string vLogText) {
   Trace.WriteLine(
        MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        + this.GetType().ToString() + vLogText);
   }
```

When I call from another project (class: TestClass, method: TestMethod)

```
Tracer.LogInfo("log this!")
```

I expect to see in the log:

```
TestClass, TestMethod, log this!
```

But instead I got

```
TracerClass, LogInfo, log this!
```

How to get the parent method and class name?

Comment: [This might help you immensely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) if you're using newest C# and VS 2012.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor This is brilliant! Wasn't aware of such a thing. Can you please make this to a answer instead of a comment so I can vote up and mark it as closed? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Neurodefekt No problem, it's done. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 33):

Try doing something like this:

```
var mth = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
var cls = mth.ReflectedType.Name;
// where 1 illustrates how deep into the stack to reflect.
```

There are more elegant solutions in C# 5.0 >, however if you are using older frameworks, the above will help.

Comment: Two things: 1) This can significantly affect performance 2) In optimized code, method inlining can cause an incorrect method name to be printed.

Comment: If performance isn't a concern, you can use MethodImpl to enforce no inlining: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`

Comment: The line
    `var cls = mth.ReflectedType.Name;` 
produces  the method type including the signature, not only the class name of the instance invoking the method.
I suggest 
    `var cls = mth.DeclaringType.Name;`
to the the class name

Answer (score 3):

You may just record the full stack trace instead of just the calling method using `Environment.StackTrace`. This may help you if you want to use the same logging structure to log exceptions.

Refer to [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) for more information.