# Get property name in the property's Set{} method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In C# 4.0 I am doing the following:

```
public string PropertyA
{
  get;
  set
  {
    DoSomething("PropertyA");
  }
}

public string PropertyB
{
  get;
  set
  {
    DoSomething("PropertyB");
  }
}
```

..I have a lot of these properties and doing it manually will be a pain. Is there a way I could replace this with:

```
public string PropertyA
{
  get;
  set
  {
    DoSomething(GetNameOfProperty());
  }
}
```

..maybe using reflection?

Comment: It doesn't help much now, but C# 6 will feature a `nameof` operator, which will do something similar to what you are looking for, and with compile-time checking. (Presumeably, you'll still have to write the property name twice everywhere, but the compiler will tell you if you misspelt it somewhere.)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Sayse Doesn't sound like it to me. This is a common pattern for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @hvd - Ah very true, its been a while since I implemented that

Comment: If you're targeting .NET Framework 4.5 you can use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14849434/1244816), it works i .Net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 4.5 your `DoSomething` method should use the `[CallerMemberName]` parameter attribute:

```
void DoSomething([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    // memberName will be PropertyB
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
public string PropertyA
{
     get
     {
         ...
     }
     set
     {
         DoSomething();
     }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) on this.

Comment: `CallerMemberNameAttribute` is not available in C# 4.0.

Comment: Did this also exists in .Net 4.0

Comment: It can work for .NET 4.0, provided you define your own `CallerMemberNameAttribute` type and use a C# 5.0 compiler. It's just in C# 4.0 that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in current C# versions, reflection won't help. You could hack this with expressions and get compile time checking, but that's about it, you'd have to type even more code too

```
 DoSomething(()=>this.PropertyA); // have dosomething take an expression and parse that to find the member access expression, you'll get the name there
```

A good alternative if that's possible for you would be to use Postsharp to do this instead in a clean way, but that may not always be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection of [`GetCurrentMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public string PropertyA
{
    get;
    set
    {
        DoSomething(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4));
    }
}
```

It's available for .Net 4.

As @hvd explains, the Name will return `set_PropertyA`, then use `Substring` to take the property name.

Comment: @Sayse The current method will be the property setter, named `set_PropertyA`. That also explains the `.Substring(4)`.

Comment: @John, is this the reflection you are looking for?