# .Net Set Class Constant to it's Namespace at compile time

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a nice way to set a constant to be that of a classes namespace?

```
namespace ACMECompany.ACMEApp.Services
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private const string WhatWeDo = "ACMECompany.ACMEApp.Services";
        private const string WouldBeNice = typeof(MyService).Namespace;

        ...

    }
}
```

So that if the class if moved to another namespace we don't need to worry about these constants.

**More Info**
The constant is only really used for logging - where it is passed to some log method.  This is all legacy code so wont be changing in the short term.  I am aware of runtime ways to get this information such as [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849367/how-to-determine-calling-method-and-class-name)

We're using .NET 4 but will be upgrading soon to .NET 4.5.

Comment: use read only instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not going to set a constant variable with a non-constant value. This is understandable, isn't it?

BTW, C# has the [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword, to turn any class field to work like a constant once object construction time ends. They can or can't be static:

```
public class MyService
{
    static MyService()
    {
         WouldBeNice = typeof(MyService).Namespace;
    }

    private static readonly string WouldBeNice;
}
```

or...

```
public class MyService
{
    private static readonly string WouldBeNice = typeof(MyService).Namespace;
}
```

Also, you can achieve the same behavior using read-only properties:

```
// Prior to C# 6...
public class MyService
{
     private static string WouldBeNice { get { return typeof(MyService).Namespace; } }
}

// Now using C# 6...
public class MyService
{
     private static string WouldBeNice => typeof(MyService).Namespace;
}

// Also using C# 6...
public class MyService
{
     // This can be even better, because this sets the namespace 
     // to the auto-generated backing class field created during compile-time
     private static string WouldBeNice { get; } = typeof(MyService).Namespace;
}
```

Comment: *You're not going to set a constant variable with a non-constant value* - but the namespace is known at compile-time, so it's not unimaginable for there to be some way to do this.

Comment: @Rawling The namespace isn't know at compile time because its name is being accessed using reflection... which is a run-time concern :\

Comment: @Rawling It could be something like the new `nameof`operator like `namespaceof`... and this would be great ;P

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when the compiler is compiling a class it knows what namespace that class is in...

Comment: @Rawling This is the reason to suggest that it would be wonderful if C# 7 may introduce a `namespaceof` keyword !!!

Comment: Heh, fair enough... Didn't notice the second comment was from you too!